# Unable to set default values in Django models

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am trying to set default values for few fields like Date, Integer and CharFields, but when I am setting it like  `default=12` (in case of integer) it is not being reflected in page. However a default value of zero is always displayed.

```
Months = models.IntegerField('Enter the month',default=12
```

Above field is a required field, hence a default 0 is displayed in form but anything other than zero is not displayed.

Same is the case with charField and DateField, In this case nothing at all is displayed in form.

I am using mySQL at backend.

I want to set default date to `'0000-00-00'` , How can I do that?

Comment: `default=12` will be applied only to new created models. Existing values in database will keep old value, until you change it explicitly.

Comment: new model mean new tables? or new data entries?

Comment: I mean new model instances in terms of django. It corresponds to new table rows. `YourModel(**data).save()` <-- new model instance was saved, i.e. new row was inserted (or updated) in SQL database

Comment: Alright. I am trying to save a new entry only. But earlier this field didn't had any default value. But now I want to set a default value for this field. All old value can remain as it is but the next time when I load the page, this should by default display default value in it.

Answer (score 2):

## **Set a default value into model**

This default value is added as you are suggesting

```
Months = models.IntegerField('Enter the month',default=12...
```

But this value will be used **only** when a object is created and you **dont receive any value to this field**

Example:

```
class Year (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    months = models.IntegerField(default=12)
```

Now in console/view you can do:

```
new_year = Year(name='any_name')
new_year.save()  # And the Year object is created with months = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the default value is actually there. If you have added the default value after you created the model and applied a syncdb, make sure you run makemigrate (on Django 1.7) or an external app like South to alter the database table. If you don't or if you only run syncdb, this change won't be reflected on your MySQL.